# Why is my title not showing in Jasper Reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a Jasper Report that has a title followed by details. When there are details in the report, the title shows. But when the report has no details, the title does not show.

I would like the title to be fixed, so that it shows no matter whether there are details or not. I already have it configured this way for a separate report. The only difference between the two reports is that the second report (which has a fixed header that shows no matter what) does not use frames, whereas this report (the problematic one) does use frames.

Here is the XML for the title section of my problematic report that does not show a fixed header.

Any idea why the title is not showing in the case that there are no report details? I do use static text, after all... I'm not sure why the static text doesn't show.

```
<title>
    <band height="60" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
        <frame>
            <reportElement style="Title" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="800" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="f5eeff7b-82c8-4e5e-b89f-c8f4e0bf230e">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
            <box padding="1">
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#666666"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#666666"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#666666"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#666666"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#666666"/>
            </box>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="332" y="0" width="134" height="20" uuid="ff17f385-30ec-417d-bf55-2f79996f0ca9">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Sign Audit Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="20" width="800" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="f9c0304d-0864-46b3-8b18-b28b20d8c7de">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
            <box padding="1">
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#666666"/>
                <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#666666"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#666666"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#666666"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#666666"/>
            </box>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="299" y="0" width="190" height="19" uuid="ace3db7b-5c61-4205-98e9-872483bc9206"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{STORE_ID} +" - "+$P{STORE_NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="40" width="800" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="b0c895f6-6dbd-477d-9858-9ad66af087e1">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
            <box padding="1">
                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#666666"/>
            </box>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="99" height="20" uuid="d37d9a5e-2dad-4774-8b62-87a458b25902">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Report generated on :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="MM/dd/yyyy">
                <reportElement x="99" y="0" width="122" height="20" uuid="e4e59db3-b1d7-4f84-8052-96d6c4ea34a1">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat($P{DATE_FORMAT_PARAM}).format(new Date())]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="MM/dd/yyyy">
                <reportElement x="641" y="0" width="150" height="20" uuid="98a8efa4-19ae-4d06-8874-12482bd8aeb1">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat($P{DATE_FORMAT_PARAM}).format($P{effStartDate})+" - "+new java.text.SimpleDateFormat($P{DATE_FORMAT_PARAM}).format($P{endDate})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="579" y="0" width="64" height="20" uuid="6dfe0bf6-cd90-48b2-9cc9-7bad865a9c66">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Signs Active :]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </frame>
    </band>
</title>
```